# Getting NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for {"name"=>"Data Set 1", "values"=>["", ""]}:Hash) error after upgrading from Rails 2.3.5 to 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hash, upgrade, slickgrid

After upgrading to Rails 2.3.11, I can no longer use SlickGrid to create what we call data sets. If you click on the toggle icon to create a data set, I get the following stack trace:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for {"name"=>"Data Set 1", "values"=>["", ""]}:Hash):
  lib/slick_data.rb:99:in `to_data_json'
  lib/slick_data.rb:97:in `map'
  lib/slick_data.rb:97:in `to_data_json'
  app/controllers/data_sets_controller.rb:11:in `index'
  haml (3.0.22) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
  airbrake (3.0.4) lib/airbrake/rack.rb:27:in `call'
  airbrake (3.0.4) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
```

Here is the 'to_data_json' code in slick_data.rb:

```
def to_data_json
  new_data = sanitized_data.map do |d|
    h = {}
    h['data_set_name'] = d.name
    j = 1
    d['values'].each do |v|
      h["var_#{j}"] = v
      j += 1
    end
    h
  end
  ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(new_data)
end
```

And here is the code for 'index' in data_sets_controller.rb:

```
def index # Ajax
  @scenario = Scenario.find(params[:scenario_id])
  sd = SlickData.new(@scenario.data_sets)
  render :json => {
    :html    => render_to_string(:layout => false, 
                                 :template => 'data_sets/index.html.erb', 
                                 :object => @scenario),
    :id      => @scenario.id,
    :data    => sd.to_data_json,
    :columns => sd.to_col_json,
  }
end
```

Do I perhaps need to upgrade my json gem? I am using 1.4.6. Or maybe I need to upgrade my version of SlickGrid? I am using version 1.4.3. Thanks.

Comment: Any json experts here? I removed .name from h['data_set_name'] = d.name and my code ALMOST works. I can see all the objects and the slickgrid, et. al. There's still a problem though: Instead of seeing a name in the Data Set Name column, I see the text "[object Object]."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just needed to change `d.name` to `d['name']` in lib/slick_data.rb and that fixed the error. I'm wondering why this even worked before, in Rails 2.3.5?